# How can I add minutes and seconds to interval

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following: `trunc(sysdate - 1) + interval '8' hour`

How can I add minutes and seconds to that interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `HOUR TO SECOND` instead of just `HOUR`:

```
SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE - 1 ) + INTERVAL '8:12:34' HOUR TO SECOND
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)+INTERVAL'8:12:34'HOURTOSECOND |
> | :--------------------------------------------- |
> | 2020-06-08 08:12:34                            |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e60f4999093adc9d0fc04dd49e02dc83)*

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
select cast(trunc(sysdate - 1) as timestamp) + interval '8' hour + interval '40' minute + interval '20' second from dual;
```

You are currently using sysdate. In the example above, I'm switching that to timestamp. Then, add 8 hours. Then, add minutes and seconds.

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=76a640ecfb4b59cfbac628511d2accd3

Comment: what does the `cast` do?

Comment: `cast` changes the datatype of date to timestamp so that the hours, minutes and seconds you add to it becomes visible.

Comment: You do not need to use `CAST`. A `DATE` data type has hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: Thank you, @MT0. I didn't know that.

Comment: @MT0 Thanks, yeah that casting was a little weird to me

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f3d7de2301cc445f1277dd1d83b20398) without the `CAST`.

Comment: The answer is unnecessarily complicated even without the cast. You can add an interval literal with hours, minutes and seconds all at once.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, it is easier to resort to the old-fashioned method:

```
select trunc(sysdate - 1) + (8 / 24 + 30 / (24 * 60) + 5 / (24 * 60 * 60))
```

Or to express it using one interval and arithmetic:

```
trunc(sysdate - 1) + (8 * 60 * 60 + 30 * 60 + 17) * interval '1' second
```

There is a syntax for composite intervals; I find Oracle's version hard to remember.